# Is it necessary to include spark-assembly in jar file?

Tags: apache-spark, deployment, dependencies

I developed a spark application by IntelliJIdea and *spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0* is one of my dependencies. I want to deploy my application to a jar file and run it by `spark-submit`. Is it necessary to include *spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0* in the jar file or including other dependencies is sufficient?

Comment: What is your language?

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski, my language is Scala.

Comment: Why don't you use sbt (or other build management tools)?

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski, Because of I couldn't download sbt for this project, I decided to use raw Scala for this project. In addition I want to experience Spark without other build management tools to understand behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [Learning Spark: Lightning-Fast Big Data Analytics](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2717070), it is not necessary to include *spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0* in the jar file:

> When you are bundling an application, you should never include
>   Spark itself in the list of submitted dependencies. spark-submit
>   automatically ensures that Spark is present in the path of your
>   program.

Answer (score 1):

Including other dependencies only is fine (and as so you should mark the dependency as provided if you use maven/sbt/...). When you run spark-submit, you'll notice in the output logs that your jar and the spark-assembly jar are both uploaded to hdfs to be used later on.